# SCCM deployment with no client on the host machine

Tags: sccm

I have a requirement where I need to deploy tools using SCCM. The trick here is there is no SCCM client available for that OS. Is there a way to deploy the tools on system which do not run SCCM client ??

Comment: What OS is it? What version of SCCM are you using?

Answer (score 2):

No, without the SCCM client there is now way for the system to receive anything.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup software called PDQ Deploy. I have used it in the past might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If the OS is a Mac I Parallels for Mac is able to tie in with SCCM. Not as much functionality as with SCCM and windows though.

Answer (score 0):

you need the SCCM client.  Another solution in this case would be using GPO to perform the action you need completed